# Golang anonymous function in loop - issues with values passed as arguments

Tags: go, closures, anonymous-function

I had read various pages such as https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes which outlined the issues with using closures and goroutines in a loop. As such I wrote my original loops as follows:

```
for outstanding < threads {
    ttl += 1;
    outstanding += 1;
    go func (ttl int, results chan Result) {
        results <- pw.SendTTL(ttl, dest)
        results <- pw.Recv(3)
    }(ttl, results)
}
```

Passing the changing TTL as an argument to the anonymous function. I ended up getting a random assortment of values over the range. Say if I was expecting 1-5 I'd get a couple 1's, a couple 3's, maybe a 4.

So I tried the following, in case there was something about specifically using the variable instantiated by the loop. Yes I know I'm sort of abusing the for loop here...

```
for i := ttl; outstanding < threads; i++ {
    go func (ttl int, results chan Result) {
        results <- pw.SendTTL(ttl, dest)
        results <- pw.Recv(3)
    }(i, results)
    outstanding++;
}
```

No joy. Same experience.

I also tried the other suggested option where you use a local variable in the loop, and use that within the closure. Same experience.

What am I doing wrong here? What boat did I miss?

Comment: Can you make a standalone example ([mcve])? What do you expect to happen, and what exactly are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In writing out the requested example I think I realized what my problem was. The various go routines were clobbering each others TTL settings when attempting to share the socket.

Question withdrawn ;)

Edit: To clarify, the right value was in fact being passed to the routines in either case. It was an underlying sharing of resources that was the problem.